# I dont want a server process which is a daemon to shut down - even on recieving kill signal. Is there any way to ensure this?

Tags: c++, signals, daemon

Assume the daemon server is running on a specific process_id

So if I give command **kill process_id** from terminal, then the daemon server process exits.
How can I handle this signal.

Also what are the other signals I need to take care of, for running the daemon server uninterrupted ?

EDIT : Operating system Ubuntu

Comment: If this is a question about a particular operating system, you'll have to tell us which one.

Comment: Take a look at 'man sigaction'

Comment: I found http://beej.us/guide/bgipc/output/html/multipage/signals.html helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can block almost all signals, with the notable exception of `SIGKILL`.

By default the `kill` command sends `SIGTERM`, which you can block.

---

Read about the [`sigaction`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/sigaction.html) system call to learn how to block signals.

Comment: Thanks, so I can block kill from command line, but if a process sends SIGKILL, then there is no way that my daemon will keep on running ?

Comment: @Anubha Correct, the `SIGKILL` signal can never be blocked, caught or ignored.

Comment: You need at least one way to kill/stop a process from running.

Comment: @Anubha No. `SIGKILL` is `kill -9`, and there's no protection against that (by design).

Answer (score 0):

The simple interface for signal is:

```
void (*singnal(int signo, void(*func)(int)))(int);
```

It is a function registering a processing function for a specific signal, indentified by a signal number.